# Decimated and windowed read in rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, resampling, image-pyramids

In my workflow using rasterio, I'd like to read an overview from a raster and get only a portion of it through a window at the same time.

Is this possible?

I have a pretty complex script so far and I'm trying to check whether the wrong output is due to this not being possible.

Basically, I am asking if it is possible to do something like this:

```
data = src.read(out_shape=(1,
                           math.ceil(src.height / 64),
                           math.ceil(src.width / 64)),
                window=window)
```

where `data` is a decimated read of `src` to get source raster overview for factor 64, and `window` has the `width` and `height` whose dimensions are relative to the source raster (not the overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sean Gillies of the rasterio team, I was able to find a solution.

Basically, it is not possible to simultaneously make a windowed AND decimated read, so the answer to my question is NO.

However, there is an undocumented (AFAIK) parameter called `overview_level` which can be passed to `rasterio.open()`.

This parameter takes the 0-based index of an overview level. So, assuming overviews are present in a source `raster`, one can do

```
src = rasterio.open(raster, overview_level=0)
```

to create a Rasterio dataset from the first level of overview of source raster.

Then, simply do a windowed read in the common format:

```
for ji, src_window in src.block_windows(1):
    arr = src.read(1, window=src_window)
```